# MongoDB explain winning plan shows "EOF"

Tags: aggregate, explain, mongodb-3.2

I've been working on optimizing my queries on some 2 million documents in MongoDB and I tried to use explain on aggregate functions, but it would display

```
"winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "EOF"
    },
```

Prior to this, the function would show the winning plan with the stages such as "Fetch", but after I tried a few different syntax in writing the aggregate command now it is showing "EOF". I tried to simplify my command to a `find().explain()` function but it is still the same. Anyone has any ideas?

On a second note, has anyone figured out how to `explain("executionStats")` on an aggregate query. I see that the function has been implemented [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19758), but when I run it I get "EOF" as well as a basic `explain()` results. Is it because my MongoDB is not updated to 3.5.5? Is this functionality supported for versions below 3.5.5? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found out why. Apparently I was querying against the admin database. Always run `use <db>` guys

Answer (score 1):

In my case, on my query I put an incorrect collection name. Always check that too.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution/participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the questions and answers posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I write a good answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (Help Centre)_ In the section **Answer the question** there is a short sentence which reads: _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._ You might want to consider [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/214872/edit) your answer and adding an example of how it should look.